# What's the adjective to the word "sibling"

Tags: adjectives, kinship-terms

I'm looking for the adjective that goes with *sibling*. My sentence would be something like:

> The [...] relationship.

So the adjective would be used to denote that the relationship is one between siblings. A native speaker told me it was simply *sibling*, however, I'm not convinced. I have tried googling for the answer, but it hasn't yielded any results as of yet.

Unfortunately, my Oxford dictionary is having a sleepover at one of my fellow students.

Comment: It is, in fact, a *sibling* relationship.  What makes you hesitant to accept this? What did you google for?  I just did and found this: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sibling%20relationship%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en

Comment: "Unfortunately, my Oxford dictionary is having a sleepover at one of my fellow students." Ahem. You don't need your Oxford dictionary to answer this question; if you can access ELU, you can access a [dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sibling).

Comment: @J.R. Yes, but my dictionary has a list with all related words. Adjective is not found at your suggested website.

Comment: @BloodPhilia: Definition 1(b) (as modifier) ⇒ sibling rivalry.  That gives you the meaning you seek.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your native speaker is right about *sibling relationship*.

If you want to talk about the relationship between brothers, there's *[fraternal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraternal)*.

Conversely, *[sororal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sororal)* is used for sisters.

Comment: There are some among us who would use "fraternal" in a gender-neutral way too.  This is what stops it from being a perfect synonym of "brotherly".

Answer (score 6):

While it is broader (and can cover relationships outside of the same generation) the term **consanguineal** [reflects](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Consanguineal?r=66) common blood relationship

> having the same ancestry or descent; related by blood.

It derives from the noun form, **consanguinity**, [meaning](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consanguineous?view=uk)

> relating to or denoting people descended from the same ancestor:

Comment: Thanks! Although your suggestions are not of the nature I need, very interesting!